# Why hard drive is displayed as virtual on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bios, lenovo-laptop

I have lenovo w540 laptop with two physical drives - SSD with system and 1tb HDD.
SSD works just fine, but HDD is wierdly mounted as virtual drive. The problem is - I can't access it outside of windows. It's not displayed in BIOS, it's not displayed in second system (ubuntu).

How can I make the disk be displayed in more 'normal' way? Any leads would be much appreciated, I dont even know where to start.

May be relevant

- Disk managment shows only virtual drive and not its physical
  representation, as well as some external programs (speccy)
- It says it's SCSI device
  (SCSI\Disk&Ven_Msft&Prod_Virtual_Disk\2&1f4adffe&0&000001)
- The HDD disk can be accessed as file on SSD drive in system folder
- The HDD partitions auto-opens on system load, like it would be with external usb-drive.
- I have "hard disk password" option in BIOS, but it's disabled. I've
  also tried to switch between uefi/legacy loading modes - didn't help.

Comment: Hard to believe a drive *not displayed in BIOS* is being detected by the OS. Please check.

Comment: It sounds like it says it is a virtual drive because it *is* a virtual drive.  Open the system up and verify that there actually is a second drive in there, and if so, try removing it and see if it affects the virtual drive.

Comment: Looks like both of you are right. I’ve found and ejected virtual drive and it disappears. Previous owner faked an hdd. I guess thats why you dont buy a second-hand laptop  .
Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.